# Conditional Global Variables OR simply not working

Tags: conditionals

I've got

```
{if segment_3 == "desc" OR segment_4 == "desc"}
```

and EE is just ignoring it or not parsing it or something. I can try

```
{if segment_3 == "desc" || segment_4 == "desc"}
```

and that doesn't work either. However, if i have `{if segment_3 == "desc"}` on it's own, that works fine.

What's going on here huh?

More of the code around this, it's in a channel:entries tag and it's to define whether a orderby and sort paramater is applied:

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="my_channel"
limit="15"
paginate="bottom"
{if segment_3 != "asc" OR segment_4 != "desc"} category={segment_3_category_id} {/if}
{if segment_3 == "desc" || segment_4 == "desc"} orderby="woa-price" sort="desc"{/if}
{/channel:entries}
```

Comment: There's more going on here - what are you doing within this conditional block which is telling you that it's not working? Can you post the code in context?

Comment: @DerekHogue There you go Derek, see above edit to original questions. Cheers for looking at this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a parse order issue. The advanced conditional gets parsed after the channel entries tag. Try something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="my_channel"
limit="15"
paginate="bottom"
category="{if segment_3 != "asc"}{segment_3_category_id}{/if}{if segment_4 != "desc"}{segment_3_category_id}{/if}"
orderby="{if segment_3 == "desc"}woa-price{/if}{if segment_4 == "desc"}woa-price{/if}"
sort="{if segment_3 == "desc"}desc{/if}{if segment_4 == "desc"}desc{/if}"
{/channel:entries}
```

Not sure if those conditions will match the URLs that you've got setup, but that is how you will have to do it. You need to use simple conditionals inside of the channel entries parameters.

Comment: Rats, i was trying to avoid that to keep the code a bit leaner. Oddly, the first advanced conditional works ok. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

You're running into a [parse order](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/53/55) issue here. This is because when you have multiple comparison operators in a conditional, that's an *advanced conditional*. Advanced conditionals are parsed *after* module tags (like `channel:entries`).

This solution might work for you though - use `preload_replace` variables:

```
{if segment_3 == 'desc'}
    {preload_replace:orderby="woa-price"}
    {preload_replace:sort="desc"}
{/if}
{if segment_4 == 'desc'}
    {preload_replace:orderby="woa-price"}
    {preload_replace:sort="desc"}
{/if}
{preload_replace:orderby="date"}
{preload_replace:sort="asc"}
```

Then you can use `orderby="{orderby}"` and `sort="{sort}` in your `channel:entries` tag.

This should work because these are simple conditionals, so they are parsed early, and because `preload_replace` variables saved based on their *first* parsed instance (so if your conditionals are met, the later declarations that are outside of the conditionals are ignored).

Comment: I went with the answer below in the end, but thanks for your help and input!!

Answer (score 1):

It may be treating the simple conditional and the complex conditional differently.  Maybe try:

```
{if '{segment_3}' == "desc" OR '{segment_4}' == "desc"}
```

See if that then parses.

Comment: Nope, same problem! I'm sure i've had this issue before and fixed it with something similar. Can't remember what now though!

Comment: Try it all with double quotes... {if "{segment_3}" == "desc" OR etc.

Comment: Are you using any add-ons that will interfere with the segment setting?